# Using protected $table variable when creating a Model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, orm, model, eloquent

Currently, I am learning about Eloquent ORM in Laravel and at the beginning, while reading about creating a model with migrating table, the book says that you can change the name of the table by defining $protected table. It is easy to define this variable with the desired name but it is obvious that it will not affect the table in MySQL. How can I use this property of the Model class?

Comment: in the model class add `protected $table = 'the_real_table_name_in_db';`

Comment: I did that and nothing changed, that is why I asked this question.

Comment: you need to tell the model, which table is used on this model, didn't means changed $table will also change the table name in the db, you need change in the table schema

Comment: So, I can not create a model with --migration flag if it creates a table with the expected "snake_case" notation. I created a model with $table at first, then migration with the name of the table same as $table. Now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will create the table using the name you prefer in your migration, then you will use:

```
protected $table = "mytablename";
```

To let Laravel know what table should it use when calling **Model::create()** or any other method.

Comment: I created a model with $table at first, then migration with the name of the table same as $table. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

lets say your table is posts. in that case if you create a model Post, laravel guesses that the table is posts automatically. but if your table name is post, and you name model Post, laravel still assumes that the table is posts. in this case you have to use this

```
protected $table = "post";
```

Hope this clears your concept.

Comment: I created a Model Post with migration flag, so when I migrated the tables it created a table called "posts" in the database. However, I want to rename it and even if I write protected $table = "post"; for example, nothing changes in the database. That is why I thought I misunderstood the functionality of this variable.

Comment: actually if you create a model, it does not create table. the table is created according to your migration file and what is the name of table you specified there. Model will just tally the name according to the rule 'table name is small case plural and model name is singular with first letter capital'.

Comment: if this is the right answer, please dont forget to mark it as right answer, so that will help others who have same question

Comment: Is using `protected $table` line to declare the table, a best practice according to Laravel standards?